# API for Conditional Highlighting cells in Matrix report

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, reporting, analytics

I have created a Matrix report with conditional highlighting.
To display this report in visualforce page I'm using Analytics API in Apex.
I'm getting all report data as expected but not getting metadata about conditional highlighting. Is there any api available to get the colors used in given report for conditional highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

To get the metadata you're looking for you perform a describe on the report. See [Get Dashboard Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_dashboard_example_get_dashboard_metadata.htm) which will show an example of the results that are returned, including the color information like in the snippet below:

```
  "visualizationProperties" : {

    "breakPoints" : [ {

      "aggregateName" : "s!AMOUNT",

      "breaks" : [ {

        "color" : "c25454",

        "lowerBound" : 100000,

        "upperBound" : 300000

      }, {

        "color" : "c2c254",

        "lowerBound" : 300000,

        "upperBound" : 800000

      }, {

        "color" : "54c254",

        "lowerBound" : 800000,

        "upperBound" : 1000000

      } ]

    } ],
```

Comment: For above solution I have to create a new dashboard.